# Granting permissions on Android 4.1.2

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, permissions

I have an old phone running Android 4.1.2. When trying to use a new app, it will try to request the necessary permissions. However, I am not able to grant them. The app will show me a dialog telling me that it requires additional permission.

[image: Dialog]

After clicking "OK", I am forwarded to the settings screen.

[image: Settings screen]

There, I cannot do anything but click back which tells the app that I haven't granted the permission.

What is the correct way to grant the permissions?

Comment: Does the phone have ANT hardware installed at all? Because an ANT app is useless without ANT hardware. Alternative you can try to connect an external ANT dongle https://www.thisisant.com/consumer/ant-101/ant-in-phones

Comment: Afaik yes. Same behaviour happens when I try to grant permissions to a different app

Comment: "*Same behaviour happens when I try to grant permissions to a different app*" could you clarify if this is not only about ANT (which is not supported on [every device](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4644/44325)) but for any permissions, like Contact, Camera, Location?

Comment: As far as I remember Android 4.1.2 does not have run-time permissions. Run-time permissions were introduced later (about Android 6).

Comment: Thanks, it seems that it is really related to a missing ANT support. But this also means that showing the settings screen on Android 4.1.2 when a permission was initially missing does only confuse users